# How to parse other type of file that aren't JSON

Tags: python, parsing

I have a file with some data in it, however it is not a JSON and I have no idea how I can parse such a format using Python or Java.

the file content looks like this

```
id: 34
account :143456
macAddress: 00-10-FA-6E-38-4A
```

Comment: Are you sure your second line is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
data = dict(line.split(": ", 1) for line in file)
```

Expanded out:

```
data = {}

for line in file:
    k, v = line.split(": ", 1)
    data[k] = v
```

Comment: thank you so much, that was helpful, can you please explain to me how this work under the hood, like what's dict and the , 1 for ? also how to make ```account :143456
macAddress: 00-10-FA-6E-38-4A``` sub or contained inside ```id```  thanks,

Comment: The 1 is there because we only want to split on the first occurrence of `": "`. ` The `dict` converts the list of key value pairs into a dictionary.